# Karma Jasmine NPM config

Tags: angularjs, node.js, configuration, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

## karma config errors

I'm trying to configure my test environment, and getting the following bugs when I try to run karma.

```
karma start
06 10 2015 13:13:36.859:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin karma-jasmine.
06 10 2015 13:13:36.917:DEBUG [karma]: List of files has changed, trying to execute
06 10 2015 13:13:36.918:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
06 10 2015 13:13:36.922:DEBUG [watcher]: Watching ".../representative-summary/node_modules/angular"
06 10 2015 13:13:36.922:DEBUG [watcher]: Watching ".../representative-summary/node_modules/angular-resource"
06 10 2015 13:13:36.923:DEBUG [watcher]: Watching ".../representative-summary/spec"
06 10 2015 13:13:36.927:WARN [launcher]: Can not load "karma-chrome-launcher", it is not registered!
  Perhaps you are missing some plugin?
06 10 2015 13:13:36.927:WARN [launcher]: Can not load "karma-firefox-launcher", it is not registered!
  Perhaps you are missing some plugin?
06 10 2015 13:13:36.928:WARN [launcher]: Can not load "karma-safari-launcher", it is not registered!
  Perhaps you are missing some plugin?
06 10 2015 13:13:36.928:WARN [launcher]: Can not load "karma-ie-launcher", it is not registered!
  Perhaps you are missing some plugin?
06 10 2015 13:13:36.928:WARN [launcher]: Can not load "karma-phantomjs-launcher", it is not registered!
  Perhaps you are missing some plugin?
```

## karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({

        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        files: [
            {pattern: 'node_modules/angular/*.js', included: true},
            {pattern: 'node_modules/angular-resource/*.js', included: true},
            {pattern: 'spec/*.spec.js', included: true}
        ],
        reporters: ['progress'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
            //config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: [
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-firefox-launcher',
            'karma-safari-launcher',
            'karma-phantomjs-launcher'
        ],
        plugins: ['karma-jasmine'],
        singleRun: false
    })
};
```

I'm on OSX Yosemite 10.10.5, and yes there is a standalone test in there "expect true to be true" just to get it up and running by itself. The app I am writing is Angular, but I haven't touched any of the tests for that yet. I want just the basic test runner to be working right first.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: That's not what you should have for your `browsers` entry. Please read the Karma manual to understand how the config file should be structured.

Comment: Aha of course. I did know this. Thanks for the tip. @MadaraUchiha, you should put it into an answer so I can give you credit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers in karma come in English format (`Chrome`, `Firefox`, `PhantomJS`), not as their respective plugin names. The plugins just have to be installed with `npm install --save`.

ALSO: Karma will "magically" load any library in your `node_modules` directory starting with `karma-`, so you don't need to declare `plugins:` at all in your configuration file.

Comment: make sure to spell it correctly, I did 'chrome' rather 'Chrome' and it did not worked for me. once i corrected the uppercase C it worked for me